# Jquery Draggable / Live

Tags: jquery, draggable, live

I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

      $(".div1, .div2, .div3, .div4, .div5").draggable();


      $("#menu").click(function () {

           $("<div class='div1'></div>").appendTo("#layout");

      });

});
```

But the draggable function works just to the divs that already exist when the page is loaded. When I add dynamically, I could not drag them.

My Html:

```
     <div id="layout">
       <div class="div1"></div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add the draggable handler to your new div with :

```
 $("<div class='div1'></div>").appendTo("#layout").draggable();
```

for example.

[Here's a live example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/qqkU7/).

Comment: The problem is, this causes draggable elements to be positioned relatively.

Answer (score 2):

In your case the easiest solution is to call `.draggable()` on the new elements as you create them, like this:

```
$("<div class='div1'></div>").appendTo("#layout").draggable();
```